# When does a process terminate in UNIX?

Tags: process, exit

At which moment a process in Unix is terminated? Is it necessary a command such as `exit(0)` or `return 0` to be written in a program to terminate a process?
My question is provoked by the following code:

```c
pid_t pid=fork();
if(pid < 0)
{
         perror("Fork error\n");
         return 1;  
}
else if (pid==0) /* child */
{
        printf("CHILD My pid is:%d\n",getpid());
}
else /* parrent */
{
         wait(NULL);
         exit(0);
}
```

In this example, in the child we do NOT call `exit(0)`(so I think we do NOT terminate the process) and in the parent we call `wait(NULL)`(so we should wait for the process to end). The program terminates, so logically at one moment the child process ends. Can you explain me when does the  child process terminate? If the child terminates after

```c
else if (pid==0) /* child */
    {
            printf("CHILD My pid is:%d\n",getpid());
    }/* Probably the child process terminates here but then what is the point of using exit(0) */
```

, well then what is the point of using `exit(0)`?

Comment: Is this a C program? It doesn't look like a complete program, and the answer may depend on seeing the rest of the code (IMHO the child process is exiting by virtue of completing the rest of the code that you haven't shown).  exit() will end the program before executing any remaining instructions.

Answer (score 3):

A C program will end in one of three conditions:

1. The program returns from the `main` function. If the return value is 0, that indicates success, otherwise the return value is the exit state. C99 also allows (but discourages) a `main` function with a `void` return type, where returning from `main` has the same semantics as returning 0 from a main with `int` return type.
2. The program returns one of the `exit` functions: `exit`, `_exit`, or the new `quick_exit` function in C11. These functions all do not return and all have the effect of terminating the program, but what they actually do differs (e.g., quick_exit flushes buffers but does not run honour `atexit` calls).
3. The OS kills the program in some way, e.g., because the program does something it is not allowed to do.

Answer (score 1):

`exit(0)` (or perhaps more ideally `exit(EXIT_SUCCESS)`) can be used to explicitly indicate that everything went well. That is, it is more of a hint to someone reading the code as to what is expected to happen, and to prevent any subsequent code from being reached (there are compiler warnings that can be enabled for unreached code). The child should probably also have an `_exit` call to indicate that it is done, as otherwise the code will fall to whatever follows the error/child/parent conditional block.

Otherwise, processes may terminate normally (via `exit`, `return` in `main`, or `_exit`), or abnormally, by calling `abort`, or by eating a signal (via `raise` or from elsewhere) that causes the program to exit.

Comment: The child process should probably call `_Exit()` to avoid flushing stdio buffers in child process, and then later the same valued bytes in parent process, calling functions registered with `atexit()`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2329640/how-to-exit-a-child-process-exit-vs-exit

Comment: Huh, Linux man page indicates "The function `_Exit()` is equivalent to `_exit()`" and OpenBSD doesn't mention any differences for them.

Comment: `_exit` is an alternative to `exit`. It has different semantics in what it actually does, but if you've run `exit`, there's no need to also do `_exit` anymore.